# Updating GridView with DataSet source

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dataset

I am working on a page to let a user import an excel file into our database. I want to allow the user to manipulate certain fields before committing the information so I loaded a DataSet from the Excel file and bound that to a GridView. For some reason on rowUpdate my NewValues collection is empty.

Here is my GridView:

```
<cc1:WWGridView ID="gvImportDisplay" runat="server" CssClass="grid-view" AllowSorting="false" ShowHeader="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
    OnRowEditing="gvImportDisplay_RowEditing"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="gvImportDisplay_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowUpdating="gvImportDisplay_RowUpdating"
    >
    <EmptyDataTemplate>0 results found. </EmptyDataTemplate>
</cc1:WWGridView>
```

And here is my code behind for the update:

```
protected void gvImportDisplay_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
    {
        string headerText = entry.Key.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerText))
            continue;
        string newValue = entry.Value.ToString();
        if (excelDataSet.Tables["ExcelInfo"].Rows[gvImportDisplay.EditIndex][headerText] == null)
            continue;
        excelDataSet.Tables["ExcelInfo"].Rows[gvImportDisplay.EditIndex][headerText] = newValue;
    }
    gvImportDisplay.EditIndex = -1;
    RefreshGridView();
}
```

"excelDataSet" is a property of the page that gets saved in the session between postbacks.

When I step through the code the foreach gets skipped completely because e.NewValues.Count = 0.

Can anyone see why the NewValues would be empty? Do I need to rebind the GridView before doing the update? Or perhaps because I don't have a DataKey it's not working? There is no column I can use as a DataKey because I can't guarantee that any particular column is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.NewValues still is not working, I'm guessing because I don't have DataKeys.

I was able to get an update working by manually defining the columns and doing a FindControl to get the new values. Since I am going to have to manually define the columns anyway for another aspect of the grid view I am going to go with that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess two way databinding doesn't work in this case. You should wrap the data set in ObjectDataSource and set this data source using GridView.DataSourceID

example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1se6685s.aspx

Comment: Ok well at least it's not just me. Thanks for the info.